# Echo PHP Array of Objects for Swift NSDictionary

Tags: php, ios, arrays, object, swift

I'm trying to build an array of objects in PHP and then echo that for use in Swift. I can get a single object to show up in Swift when I do `println` on the JSON object, but I need many objects echoed.

```
class catRow{
    public $id;
    public $person;
    public $item;
    public $descr;
    public $link;
    public $price;
}

$prepare_string = "SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY person LIMIT 5";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($prepare_string);
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $catRow = new stdClass;
    $catRow-> id = $row['id'];
    $catRow-> person = $row['person'];
    $catRow-> item = $row['item'];
    $catRow-> descr = $row['descr'];
    $catRow-> link = $row['link'];
    $catRow-> price = $row['price'];
    $allRows[] = $catRow;
}

echo json_encode($allRows);
```

And then on the Swift side I have (summarized):

```
let catalogueRows: NSDIctionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary

println(catalogueRows)
```

This works when I echo `$catRow` but I want to echo each row from that table in my database.

Comment: what println(catalogueRows) prints?

Comment: The `fetch` function returns a boolean, so I don't think your `while` loop is right. I'd call `bind_result` to bind these results to variables, and then use those when defining `catRow`. Or alternatively, use `get_result` (if you're using the MySQL native driver only), and then use `fetch_assoc` or `fetch_array` to retrieve data for the `$row` variable like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `allRows` is an array, not a dictionary. So you should cast `catalogueRows` to a `NSArray`:

```
var error: NSError?
if let catalogueRows = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: nil, error: &error) as? NSArray {
    // successful, do something with `catalogueRows`
    println(catalogueRows)
} else {
    println("parse error: /(error)")
}
```

Or, perhaps even better, cast it to an array of Swift dictionaries:

```
var error: NSError?
if let catalogueRows = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: nil, error: &error) as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    // successful, do something with `catalogueRows`
    println(catalogueRows)
} else {
    println("parse error: /(error)")
}
```

Note, in both of these cases, I (a) capture the `error` object; and (b) use the `if let` syntax to gracefully handle failures.